# Why do HK chefs let water faucets run unceasingly, when the basin overflows?

Tags: chinese-cuisine

Doesn't this waste water?  I screen-shot [7:45](https://youtu.be/E7yj3Fi3R38?t=465) of Executive Chef Sze Man Sui  at Yè Shanghai on Kowloon Hong Kong.

[image]

and [0:42](https://youtu.be/7kuzn2TC1cs?t=42) of Paul Lau at  Tin Lung Heen, Ritz-Carlton HK.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This appears to be a [dipper well](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipper_well): a continuously running sink used to rinse utensils. The water runs continuously to remove contaminants, always leaving a clean supply of water to rinse dirty utensils and, in this case, to clean out the wok.

They are rather wasteful: the linked article states they use 30-60 gallons (110 to 230 L) of water per hour.

Answer (score 2):

[The overflowing water doubles as coolant too](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Syn7o5VRnBw), these workburners put out enough BTU to heat the range to unsafe levels.

Answer (score 0):

In a kitchen its all about speed and efficiency after each dish they cook they clean out the wok. Its just easier to let the water run instead of turning it on/off every min.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add that these faucets provide an easy-to-access source of water for cooking. Chinese recipes often call for a small amount of water to be added to the wok during the cooking process. Given the amount of heat put out by those professional Chinese cooking stations, a few seconds to turn on the tap could easily spoil a dish (esp. stir-fries).